# Understanding Mat Table and DataSource re: error handling

Tags: angular, typescript, error-handling, angular-material

I am trying to handle backend errors that could possibly arise while grabbing data for my MatTable

From how I understand it, it goes

`service` --> `DataSource` --> `component`

I want my errors to reach the component so I can (possibly) display them to the user.

The behaviour I'm seeing is: the datasource doesn't "see" the error and simply returns nothing to the component when an error occurs. I am completely misunderstanding how this system should work. Most of the examples I've seen use the following code in their DataSource implementation:

```
loadContact() {
    this.loadingSubject.next(true);
    this.contactsService
      .getContact()
      .pipe(
        catchError(() => of([]))  // <----- what is going on here?
        finalize(() => this.loadingSubject.next(false)),
      )
      .subscribe((contacts) => this.contactSubject.next(contacts));
  }
```

I thought maybe if I threw an error in the `service`, it would then be caught here in `catchError`, but that isn't the case. None of the examples I could find really handle errors at all and I'm not sure what `catchError` even does in this case.

Here is my implementation:

#### contact.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Apollo } from 'apollo-angular';
import { Observable, Subscription, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { GET_ORGANIZATION_CONTACT_QUERY } from '../shared/queries/contact';
import { ErrorHandlerService } from './error-handler/error-handler.service';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ContactService {
  getContactsSub: Subscription;

  constructor(
    private apollo: Apollo,
    private errorHandler: ErrorHandlerService,
  ) {}

  getContact(): Observable<any> {
    const query = GET_ORGANIZATION_CONTACT_QUERY;
    // const variables = { organizationId: 6 };
    const variables = { organizationId: 69 }; // forces backend error for testing

    return this.apollo
      .watchQuery<any>({ query, variables })
      .valueChanges.pipe(
        map(
          (response) => {
            const { data, errors } = response;

            if (errors) {
              throw throwError(this.errorHandler.handleErrors(errors));
            }

            const { contact = {} } = data;

            return contact;
          },
          (error) => {
            throw throwError(error);
          },
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

#### error-handler.service.ts

```
/*
basically maps errors to specific messages I want to display to users.
*/

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Errors } from './error';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ErrorHandlerService {
  errors: object = Errors;

  constructor() { }

  handleErrors(errors: any): string {
    const errorCode: string = errors[0].extensions.code;
    let errorMessage: string = '';
    
    // construct a string of relevant error messages to be passed to the 
    // user
    Object.keys(this.errors).map((key) => {
      if (errorCode === key) {
        errorMessage += this.errors[key].message;
      }
    });

    return errorMessage;
  }
}
```

#### error.ts

```
export const Errors = {
  NOT_FOUND: { message: 'Not found' },
  CONTACT_NOT_FOUND: { message: 'Contact could not be found' },
  EMAIL_ALREADY_EXISTS: { message: 'Email already exists' },
  ENTITY_ALREADY_EXISTS: { message: 'Entity already exists' },
  ENTITY_NOT_FOUND: { message: 'Entity could not be found' },
  INVALID_COUNTRY_CODE: { message: 'Invalid country' },
  INVALID_HOME_JURISDICTION: { message: 'Invalid home jurisdiction' },
  INVALID_ORG_TYPE: { message: 'Invalid organization type' },
  INVALID_PROV_OR_STATE: { message: 'Invalid province or state' },
  INVALID_REQUEST: { message: 'Invalid request' },
  INVALID_USER_ROLE: { message: 'Invalid user role' },
  OKTA_ERROR: { message: 'Okta error' },
  ORG_NOT_FOUND: { message: 'Organization could not be found' },
  ORG_ALREADY_ENTITY: {
    message: 'Organization is already defined as an Entity',
  },
  ORG_POSITION_NOT_FOUND: {
    message: 'Organization position could not be found',
  },
  ORG_WITH_CAN_ALREADY_EXISTS: {
    message: 'Organization with given can number already exists',
  },
  ORG_WITH_NAME_AND_JURISDICTION_ALREADY_EXISTS: {
    message:
      'Organization with given name and jurisdiction already exists',
  },
  POSITION_NOT_FOUND: { message: 'Position could not be found' },
  TOKEN_NOT_FOUND: { message: 'Token could not be found' },
  TOKEN_WITH_EMAIL_ALREADY_EXISTS: {
    message: 'Token with given email already exists',
  },
  UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION: { message: 'Unhandled exception' },
  USER_ALREADY_EXISTS: { message: 'User already exists' },
  USER_NOT_FOUND: { message: 'User could not be found' },
};
```

#### contact-data-source.ts

```
import { CollectionViewer, DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { ContactService } from './contact.service';
import { catchError, finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class ContactDataSource implements DataSource<any> {
  private contactSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Array<any>>([]);
  private loadingSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  public loading$ = this.loadingSubject.asObservable();

  constructor(private contactsService: ContactService) {}

  connect(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer): Observable<Array<any>> {
    return this.contactSubject.asObservable();
  }

  disconnect(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer): void {
    this.contactSubject.complete();
    this.loadingSubject.complete();
  }

  loadContact() {
    this.loadingSubject.next(true);
    this.contactsService
      .getContact()
      .pipe(
        catchError((error) => {
          // this code is never executed
          console.log('inside loadContact; error:', error);
          return of(error);
        }),
        finalize(() => this.loadingSubject.next(false)),
      )
      .subscribe((contacts) => this.contactSubject.next(contacts));
  }
}
```

#### contacts.component.ts

```
import {
  AfterViewInit,
  Component,
  OnInit,
  ViewChild,
} from '@angular/core';
import { CrumbModel } from '../../shared/models/crumb.model';
import {
  MatDialog,
  MatTableDataSource,
  MatPaginator,
} from '@angular/material';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { ContactDataSource } from 'src/app/services/contact-data-source';
import { ContactService } from 'src/app/services/contact.service';
import { contactFilter } from 'src/app/shared/filters/contact.filter';
import { AddContactComponent } from 'src/app/shared/components/add-contact/add-contact.component';
import { Observable } from 'apollo-link';
import { Subject, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contacts',
  templateUrl: './contacts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contacts.component.scss'],
})
export class ContactsComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  public dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<ContactDataSource>();
  public crumbs: CrumbModel[];

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: false }) paginator: MatPaginator;

  constructor(
    public dialog: MatDialog,
    public contactService: ContactService,
  ) {}

  async ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = contactFilter;

    this.crumbs = [
      { label: 'Contacts', link: '/contacts' },
      { label: 'Contact Name', link: '/contacts/' },
      { label: 'Contact Detail', link: '' },
    ];

    this.contactService.getContact().subscribe(
      (response) => {
        // this code is never executed when an error occurs 
        // this is where I'd like to see the error message and display it
        console.log('response:', response);
        let contacts = [];
        contacts.push(response);
        this.dataSource.data = contacts;
      },
      (error) => {
        error.subscribe((error) => console.error(error));
      },
    );
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }

  handleOnSearchChange(value: string) {
    this.dataSource.filter = value.trim().toLocaleLowerCase();
    if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
      this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
    }
  }

  handleSortChange() {}

  openDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AddContactComponent, {
      width: '760px',
      data: {},
    });

    dialogRef
      .afterClosed()
      .subscribe((result: FormGroup | undefined) => {});
  }
}
```

Comment: `catchError(() => of([]))` does nothing in this context. What is your question?

Comment: can you highlight the code and issue you are facing ? and try creating a demo on stackblitz

Comment: @Allabakash did you see the commented code? and where it doesn't execute? I'll try and get a stackblitz going

Comment: @dev I want my errors to reach the component so I can (possibly) display them to the user.